# SSRS 2012 Sum report field containing First aggregate

Tags: reporting-services, aggregate

A field in my report contains First:

```
=
iif(First(Fields!Qty_BO.Value) <= 0, 0, 
    iif(isnothing(first(Fields!Qty_BO.Value)) And sum(Fields!Qty_Shipped.Value) <= 0, 
         0, 
         First(Fields!Qty_BO.Value) * first(Fields!unitprce.Value)
    )
).
```

I need to sum the values from each row by group and then grand total.  Most of the posts I've seen address summing expressions where Sun is the aggregate, but the First aggregate makes it more difficult.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using First instead of just Sum?

If you are trying to sum by row as long as you doing it on the grouping it should work and if you have a grand total just insert a row outside of the group and it should allow you to sum for grand total.